# Extract the PID from an array

Tags: powershell

I am using the following command to sort the process based on Virtual Memory Utilization:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Process | Sort PagedMemorySize64 -Desc | Select Id, Name, PagedMemorySize64 , VirtualMemorySize64 -First 10 |sls jqlserver

@{Id=37724; Name=jqlserver; PagedMemorySize64=3147898880; VirtualMemorySize64=27032002560}
```

My question how do I extract this the PID value 37724 to a variable $PID1. I tried so many things parsing arrays in Powershell, somehow I am unable to get it. Could you please provide me an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're only interested in the **jqlserver** process, in which case, you wouldn't have a need to use `Select-String` (`sls`), PowerShell cmdlets outputs objects in general and there is no need to parse them:

```
$process = Get-Process -Name jqlserver | Sort-Object PagedMemorySize64 -Descending |
           Select-Object Id, Name, PagedMemorySize64, VirtualMemorySize64 -First 10
$pid1 = $process[0].Id
```

`$process[0]` on above example, refers to the first element (**Index 0** - see [about_Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#reading-an-array)) of the array of objects (`object[]`) generated by `Get-Process` followed by `.Id` refers to the `Id` property and gets it's value.

See [about_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.2#property-values) for more useful information.

Comment: It did work, sorry for the confusion. Thank you so much for the command.